# How do I force git to think a file is unmerged?

Tags: git, ruby-piston

I want to make changes to a file in my repo, then force git to believe the file is unmerged and show up in `git status` like so:

```
# Unmerged paths:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#   (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)
#
#       both modified:      lib/delayed/recipes.rb
#
```

That's the entirety of my question. Read on for an explanation of why, since I know that's the first thing that will be asked.

The purpose here is a bugfix for [Piston](http://piston.rubyforge.org/) which today leaves merge conflicts in the index where they are too easily overlooked.

The way `piston update` works with a Git repo is:

- Clone the remote repo into a new temporary git repo
- Checkout that temp repo to the last commit we saw (saved in .piston.yml)
- Checkout our local repo (in a new branch) to the last commit where .piston.yml was updated
- Copy our local repo's files into the temp repo
- Commit all changes in the temp repo (these are our local changes as of the last time we updated this vendored project)
- Run `git merge master` in the temp repo to merge our local changes with the remote repo's changes
- IGNORE MERGE CONFLICTS(!) and copy all the files from the temp repo to our local repo
- Commit those files (in our new temp branch) to our local repo
- Checkout local repo back to our original starting point
- Merge temp branch into local repo (adds any further changes we have made)

I expect to fix this problem by allowing the file with merge conflicts to be committed into the temp branch, but at the very end (after it runs `git merge --squash`) I want to tell git about the files that had a merge conflict in the temp repo.

Comment: See "How to selectively recreate merge state?" thread on Git mailing list: http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/135059

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Git file that has a merge conflicts has (usually) three versions in index, and a version in working area with `diff3 -E` / `rcsmerge` conflict markers.  The versions in the index are stage 1 from common ancestor, stage 2 for "our" version, and stage 3 for "theirs" version.  For unmerged file there is no version in stage 0 (you can use `git update-index --unresolve` to restore unmerged state by deleting stage 0).

You would need to use `git ls-files --stage` or `git ls-tree <commit>` to get sha-1 identifiers of blobs (file versions) you want to put in index, or `git hash-object -w <file>` if you want to generate version of a file from scratch / from working area version.  Then you use `git update-index --index-info` to put higher order stages into the index file (and `git update-index --unresolve` after this, or `git update-index --force-remove` prior to stuffing higher stages to remove stage 0 from index).  You can re-generate file with merge markers in working area using `git checkout --conflict=merge -- <file>`.

HTH (Hope That Helps)

---

**See also:** "[How to selectively recreate merge state?](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/135059)" thread on Git mailing list.

Comment: The two file versions that had the merge conflict are in another repo, and may have had a third version merged in by now. Isn't that a problem? (Though I confess I don't yet understand your response completely.)

Comment: I'm beginning to understand better. I think I would have to set it up to appear as an octopus merge, no? Merging common ancestor plus vendor changes plus local changes. This is way more complex than I anticipated and I don't think I'm up for it anymore. Thanks for the answer, though.

Comment: No octopus: merges are 3-way merges in Git, therefore three versions needed.  I'll try to come up with an example later.