# Why git says "both modified" when outputting git status after conflict?

Tags: git

When having a conflict on a file while trying to merge in git, git says `both modified` on the file that has a conflict like this:

```
$ git status
On branch master
You have unmerged paths.
  (fix conflicts and run "git commit")

Unmerged paths:
  (use "git add <file>..." to mark resolution)

      both modified: file1

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Not sure why exactly "**both** modified". Does anybody of you know?

Comment: It's modified "since" or compared to both parents.

Comment: So this is just a hint, that this file has been changed in both parent commits, which is actually super obvious (otherwise there wouldn't be a conflict, right)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

This gets back to Git 1.6.5 (Oct. 2009) and [commit 4d4d572](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d4d5726aee31522e90df21ef62ee3377c5d8f8d), which introduced this more detailed message :

### `status`: show worktree status of conflicted paths separately

> **When a path is unmerged in the index, we used to always say "unmerged"** in the "Changed but not updated" section, even when the path was deleted in the work tree.
>
> Remove unmerged entries from the "Updated" section, and **create a new section "Unmerged paths".  Describe how the different stages conflict in more detail** in this new section.

As you can see in this patch, "both modified" (in both parents) is *not* the only conflict case.

```
case 1: how = "both deleted:"; break;
case 2: how = "added by us:"; break;
case 3: how = "deleted by them:"; break;
case 4: how = "added by them:"; break;
case 5: how = "deleted by us:"; break;
case 6: how = "both added:"; break;
case 7: how = "both modified:"; break;
```

---

You see more cases in [commit 173e6c8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/173e6c8852be3c543689f8613ddf3fdafd9ca7b9), with `git status -s`:

> For unmerged entries,
>
> - `X` shows the status of stage #2 (i.e. `ours`) and
> - `Y` shows the status of stage #3 (i.e. `theirs`).

```
X          Y     Meaning
-------------------------------------------------
D           D    unmerged, both deleted
A           U    unmerged, added by us
U           D    unmerged, deleted by them
U           A    unmerged, added by them
D           U    unmerged, deleted by us
A           A    unmerged, both added
U           U    unmerged, both modified
```

That illustrates the fact an index in git has **3 stages** (see "[How do I force git to think a file is unmerged?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1869991/6309)")

> In Git file that has a merge conflicts has (usually) three versions in index, and a version in working area with `diff3 -E` / `rcsmerge` conflict markers.
>
> - The versions in the index are stage 1 from common ancestor,
> - stage 2 for "our" version, and
> - stage 3 for "theirs" version.
>
> For unmerged file there is no version in stage 0

Here, "both modified" is "modified in 'ours' and 'theirs'.