# git diff extended header `index` 2nd hash corresponds to what

Tags: git

I don't understand what the second hash `..8e1e71d` means here:

```
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt
index 6a69f92..8e1e71d 100644
--- a/file.txt
+++ b/file.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-f
+f1
```

I've got this output after doing the following:

```
echo "f" > file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m "1st"
echo "f1" > file.txt
git diff
```

The first hash corresponds to the file version in the first commit, but what's the second hash? If I add this new version of the file into index, then I assume the second hash will correspond to the version of file in the index. But the file changes is not in the index yet and so there is no blob yet created in the db. I've tried:

```
git cat-file -p 8e1e71d
```

And got the following:

```
fatal: Not a valid object name 8e1e71d
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`diff man` page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-index) has an option which gives a clue as to the nature of those SHA1:

```
--full-index
```

> Instead of the first handful of characters, show the full **pre- and post-image blob object names** on the "index" line when generating patch format output.

As explained in "[Git Internals - Git Objects](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)", you can see the second SHA1 as computed from the working tree content with [**`git hash-object`**](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-hash-object):

```
 git hash-object -- file.txt
 8e1e71d...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have you had a chance to take a look at my [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29242382/what-are-the-mechanics-of-git-revert-command)?