# What are the mechanics of git-revert command

Tags: git

How does git-revert work? Does it make a patch or list of patches (only in reverse) which it then applies, or does it simply copy paths from the old commit into the new commit?

Comment: If you really want the answer "in greatest details possible", maybe you should read [the source code](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/builtin/revert.c).

Comment: @Chris, I haven't found implementation in the code you mentioned. Can you please point me to the gist of code where as suggested by `rekh127` the reverse patches are being created and applied?

Comment: I linked to `revert.c`. That's where I'd start looking, but I'm not sure exactly where you'll end up. Git's a big project; it probably isn't as simple as "look on line X of file Y".

Answer (score 1):

It makes new commits, the effect of which is to undo the previous commit. Basically it makes an opposite patch of the patch in the commit you're reverting it, and commits that patch as a new commit.