# How to flag files back as "Unmerged path" during a git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

During rebase, git status listed some files in three categories: "Changes to be committed", "Unmerged paths" and "Changes not staged for commit".
After `git add .`, All files from "Unmerged paths" were moved to "Changes to be committed".
How can I move them back, so my merge tool can recognize them and help me resolve?

Note: "git update-index --unresolve" seems to be intended for that, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1869991/2004857), but it's giving me `Not in the middle of a merge.` (apparently because a rebase is treated differently).

Comment: It's more of a workaround thatn a solution, but can't you abort the rebase, redo it and this time not go for `git add .`? I do realize it's not always desired to start from scratch with the rebase, but maybe in your case...

Answer (score 0):

```
git reset
```

Unstages your working changes. (Or more technically, resets the index).

The files will be unchanged, but no longer ready-for-comit.

Comment: Files will not be marked as unresolved in that case, will they?

Comment: I believe so. You'd have to `stage` them again as usual, then `git rebase --continue` after fixing any conflicts.